# Task Parallelism via C# 10 tasks at a time for say 100 similar tasks

Tags: c#, threadpool, task-parallel-library

I have WCF service in a managed Window service. There can be several service request through asp.net web page at a time (say 100 requests) to access this service. I am applying lock in the wcf service as i was facing some other issue. Since i am applying lock the request is getting timed out when i load test it. Is it possible to run 10 parallel task and as each tasks get completed new tasks should be created and executed for the remaining 90 tasks. i am trying to optimize my memory and also that way i need not increase the timeouts for my WCF

Comment: `I am applying lock in the wcf service as i was facing some other issue`. So dont do it! :)) You know the problem is the locks. Applying locks at such a high level as the WCF service is suicide. Explain the problem you are facing and people can help here.

Comment: Your best bet is going to be to find a way to eliminate that lock.  Can you post some code that illustrates how you are using the lock?

Comment: 1) If you *need* the lock, then there is no way around it. 2) Your system should be designed for multiple requests. 3) Placing a lock to wait for the response causes your tasks to become serialized which means more threads will get pulled out of the thread pool 4) Sounds like your system needs a better design. It does not sound scalable and will probably need to be fixed/redesigned sometime in the future.  Without knowing the design, we can't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a lock, you could use a semaphore with a maximum count of 10

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx

Comment: I voted you up because it's a good answer to the question provided, but I think he has a fundamental design flaw. If he has to place a lock to fix an "issue", there is a good chance a semaphore will also create that same issue, just less often.

Comment: -1. Problem is the lock itself. Using semaphore is a more invasive/dangerous approach while not solving the main issue.

Comment: @Aliostad: "Technically" the question was how to limit the resource to 10 tasks at a time. I do agree it side steps the underlying issue, but the OP question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible. See this MSDN document on setting up continuations:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612(VS.110).aspx

(I am assuming by "Task" you are referring to the Task object in the Task Parallelism Library)